# PHP Wordpress SEO page title help?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a Wordpress theme and I know how to call the post name (`<?php wp_title(); ?>`) but I want to replace it with the SEO page title for specific posts (using [All in one SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/)). How do I call the SEO title for a single post?

Answer (score 1):

All in one SEO should do it automatically for you. Make sure you have the `Rewrite Titles` option in the settings of All in one SEO activated.